# Fez crashing back to game library after a minute of play

Tags: technical-issues, fez

While trying to solve the 'security question' puzzle, my game crashed back to the game library.

Now every single time I try to get back into the game, it crashes back to the game library after about a minute of play. I tried staying in the room or running as fast as possible but the game still crashes.

The Polytron team acknowledged the bugs on [their website](http://polytroncorporation.com/fez-issues), and offered workarounds via email. I tried mailing them, but haven't gotten a response yet.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried several things and found one workaround for the issue.

I created a new game of Fez with another gamer profile and got the first two cubes without running into trouble. I then switched back to my gamer profile and my game doesn't crash anymore.

(I created this question to let people know about this workaround—if you know of another, please answer too!)